# Azure DevOps search/codesearchresults API not able to get more than 2000 results?

Tags: azure-devops

When I send a POST API request to
"https://MYAZUREINSTANCE/tfs/COLLECTION/MYPROJECT/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=7.0"
with this payload:

```
{
 "searchText": "ext:dll",
 "$skip": 1000,
 "$top": 1000,
 "filters": [
  {
    "name": "ProjectFilters",
      "values": [
        "MYPROJECT"
      ]
  },
  {
    "name": "RepositoryFilters",
    "values": [
      "$/MYPROJECT"
    ]
  }
 ],
 "searchFilters": {
   "ProjectFilters": [
     "MYPROJECT"
   ],
    "RepositoryFilters": [
       "$/MYPROJECT"
    ]
  }
}
```

the API returns the file data correctly.
but I have more than 2000 such files.
if I set

```
"$skip": 2000,
```

it returns an error stating that the $skip must be between 0 and 1000....

How do I get the rest of the files?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I generated 3000+ files (Create_CodeSearchResults-1-3000.md) in my repo to test the query results and also reproduced the same issue. Besides, I noticed the limitation also affected the Code Search results in web UI.
[image]

As of now, I am afraid there is no way to bypass this limit which has the query results output at most 2000 results.

Would you consider adding some other filters (`Path` or `Branch`) into your payload like in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/code-search-results/fetch-code-search-results?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to reduce the total results?

Regarding the current limitation, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.